# I have been puking for days on end

Tags: riddle

> I feel quite sick
> My symptoms indicate death
> I have been puking for days on end
> My hair is a mess
> I feel bloated beyond belief
> And with my fever I will be dead by the end of the week

What am I, and what disease am I suffering from?

Hint

> I forgot to mention that I some pretty extreme heartburn as one of my symptoms.

Comment: ...Are you sure you shouldn't be going to a hospital instead of posting on Puzzling.SE? :P

Comment: I don't know if the 3 I's are anything

Comment: @Deusovi Nah, I think I will be just fine. Probably just a case of riddle-itis, lol.

Comment: @bleh ***I*** cannot say. XD

Comment: Gluten poisoning?

Comment: @Mithrandir the disease is not conventional. Or at least, the symptoms do not generally be assumed with this disease.

Comment: Please tell whether it should be moved to [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) :P

Comment: @ABcDexter clearly you do not understand the concept of a riddle.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck On my side, that was sarcasm! Please read the **:P** again :P

Comment: @ABcDexter oh. Sorry. XD

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It's fine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a:

> Volcano undergoing an explosive eruption?

I feel quite sick, My symptoms indicate death, And with my fever I will be dead by the end of the week:

> The violent nature of the eruption may be sickening if a volcano were to be a sentient being. After an eruption, a volcano can be dormant.

I have been puking for days on end:

> This may be in reference to the magma and ash released. The eruption may take place over several days.

My hair is a mess:

> This may be in reference to the cloud of ash that forms above the volcano that may resemble messy hair.

I feel bloated beyond belief:

> An explosive eruption occurs when gas buildup causes pressure that can't be easily released. Again, if a volcano were a sentient being it may feel bloated.

Hint:

> The heat from the magma may be the cause of this. More physiologically, heartburn is caused from acid entering the esophagus, and in a volcano magma travels from under the earth's surface up through the volcano.

Disclaimer:

> This post is based entirely on my limited knowledge of volcanoes, and may contain factually inaccurate claims.

Comment: I'm actually a mountain with a disease thank-you-very-much but I'll let the prejudicial remark stand. ;) Under that context think what my hair might have actually been before it got removed and made a mess all over the place. I like to die my hair, btw.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are

> A massive star

And you are

> Going supernova.

I feel quite sick

> The balance between gravity holding the star's matter together and the core pressure caused by nuclear reactions is finally upset once the nuclear fuel is exhausted.

My symptoms indicate death

> A supernova is an event that occurs during the latter stages of a massive star's life.

I have been puking for days on end

> When a star explodes as a supernova, the outer parts are expelled violently into space.

My hair is a mess

> This reminds me of the [No-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) in which hair refers to information about the matter forming the black hole. In the case of a supernova, you could say there is a lot of hair and it is very messy.

I feel bloated beyond belief

> The core of the star becomes massive.

And with my fever I will be dead by the end of the week

> In many cases, the core of the star collapses into a black hole ("death")

Hint

> "Extreme heartburn" could refer to the increased temperature inside the core of the star during this phase of its life.

Comment: Nope, it is not a star!